# Powershell and System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2

Tags: security, powershell, certificate, x509certificate, x509

i'm getting this error when i run the system.security namespace. This is what i am running after

```
$cert=New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("C:\mycert.cer")

New-Object: Cannot find type [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("C:\mycert.cer")]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded. 
At line:1 char:19
    + $cert = New-Object <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand**
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The commands looks ok. I can't reproduce the error in PowerShell v1 or v2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved my problem. It's easily:

```
cd\
$cert=New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("C:\mycert.cer")
```

cd\ is necessary

Comment: Yes, you have a type not found error here, not a path problem. You should not have put the file into c:\ anyway, we assume you did find your actual error though! 
In Powershell: 
Use resolve-path to resolve the full path to the file, and pass that to the method. Remember whenever doing a method call in powershell, the cwd is not always what you think it is. $pwd is not equal to the runtime working directory (even excluding arguments over providers.)

Answer (score 4):

Try running this to see if you have the System.dll loaded (should be by default):

```
[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | 
    Where {$_.Location -match '\\System\\'}
```

If it is loaded then this command should show the `X509Certificate2` type:

```
[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | 
Where {$_.Location -match '\\System\\'} | 
%{$_.GetExportedTypes()} | Where {$_.Name -match 'X509Cert'}
```

If the System.dll isn't loaded (which would be odd) try loading it:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System
```

See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849914.aspx

Answer (score 3):

FYI ... I got error:

```
Unable to find type [System.Security.Cryptography.x509Certificates.X509Certificate2UI]
```

when using:

```
$certSelect = [System.Security.Cryptography.x509Certificates.X509Certificate2UI]::SelectFromCollection($certCollection, $title, $msg, 0)
```

However, I had no error creating the collection earlier on in my script:

```
$certCollection = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection
```

To make the error go away I had to include the following at some point earlier on:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this in the ISE (but seems to apply to the normal command window too) and it seems that using autocomplete will automatically `Add-Type` for whatever you're looking for. If you start a new instance and run:

```
[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | grep Security
```

it will not return `System.Security`, but if you then type this and let intellisense do its thing:

```
[System.
```

You can then run this again:

```
[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | grep Security
```

And it will then return `System.Security`. So this is why you can write a script that works fine, and then revisit it later and it's broken. Using intellisense doesn't fix your script though, instead you have to add this line:

```
Add-Type System.Security
```

Or whatever library is not getting auto-added (it seems to need the dll filename, e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Security.dll`).

I'm pretty sure IseSteroids (a paid ISE add-in) can detect this, maybe others as well.